# Error is undefined when to callback function not throwing error

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
var callback = dojo.lang.hitch(this, this.getCallbackReview); //This is used to call callback funstion after line2
this.service.ReviewManager.getReview(callback, path, ItemPath, true); //use to call java method which returns Pojo

//This is callback function
getCallbackReview: function(info, error) {
    if(error) {
        alert(error); //in case of any error from the java method
        return;
     }
     alert(info); //If no error thrown from Java Method
},
```

The second is not throwing any error and returning proper info but if this info has `clob` field then giving me error as undefined.

Comment: either it will be `java` or `javascript`

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: Can i get help on this ?

Comment: @Requester Please consider positing a sample of your code which reproduce your issue so we can help with more details. By the way... I have tried to answer your question, please let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
var callback = dojo.lang.hitch(this, this.getCallbackReview);
```

You pass as as scope `this.getCallbackReview` but this property is not defined in your code snippet.
To fix it you should consider adding `getCallbackReview` as property so

```
this.getCallbackReview = function(info, error) {
   ...
},
```

or alternativelly:

```
var callback = dojo.lang.hitch(this, getCallbackReview);
```

Comment: Still issue exist.

Comment: @Requester could you please post on jsfiddle or similar your source code in a minimal form so I can look at it and try to fix it?

Comment: Issue resolved. I have just clone the oject and remove the Clob from object and it works fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Requester ok great please consider upvoting my answer if you found it useful , licking icon arrow up on answer let's side :) thanks